# django summernote not working properly

Tags: django, django-templates, rich-text-editor, django-template-filters, django-wysiwyg

I am using [django-summernote](https://github.com/lqez/django-summernote) as a wysiwyg editor. And till now, I can save the post from the summernote editor and can display it too using the `safe` filter. But some of its functionalities are not there in my template.

1. There is no image upload button in the editor.
2. The `Code` style is displaying fine, but the `Quote` style is displaying just a regular text.

And finally, is it safe to use `safe` filter in the templates?

Please help me how do I solve this problem. Or I can't use it in django? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

`summernote` toolbar is configurable, but there is no backend/model for storing image/attachment (yet), so I disabled it by default. This issue is already posted at [github issue](https://github.com/lqez/django-summernote/issues/5) of `django-summernote`.

Another problem - about styling paragraph is also posted in above issue.

And `safe` filter must be used for displaying HTMLs without escaping. See this [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatefilter-safe).